# What does the Unity Desktop Integration extension do in Firefox?

Tags: firefox-extensions

I am using firefox 28.0 on Ubuntu 13.10.
Want to know what does the Unity Desktop Integration extension do in firefox.
Then I can enable or disable it according to the use of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It allows websites to integrate into the dash, launcher and hud. Makes an easier connection between your frequently used websites and unity. You can read about some of the webapps available here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/list-of-that-websites-support-unitys-new-web-apps-feature

An example of what it can do: add the website icon to your launcher and allows you direct access to some of its features by right-clicking the icon and could be: compose new email, unread mails in your inbox.

Comment: It is enabled on my computer, but no websites ask for integration with Firefox or Chrome. What do I do? (Also, I'm on 14.04.)